# Is there a clean way to write multi-lines strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

It sounds like a beginner question, but I never succeeded in writing long strings in a clean way in Python.

Here are the 4 ways I listed to do it. None of them seems ok to me.

```
def useless_func():
    # WRONG WAY A : string_A displays well but breaks the 80 char max PEP 8 recommandation
    string_A = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

    # WRONG WAY B : string_B will create unwanted spaces between word 'sed' and 'do' when printed
    string_B = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed\
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

    # WRONG WAY C : string_C displays well  but makes my code ugly because it breaks indentation
    string_C = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed\
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

    # WRONG WAY D : string_D (triples quotes) has the same problem than string_B (unwanted spaces)
    string_D = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'''
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
string = "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf" \
         "sdfsdfsdfsdfs"
```

And the result:

```
>>> string
'sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs'
```

The same effect can be achieved by using paranthesis instead of `\`, as @Nigel Tufnel mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 13):

I would go with:

```
def pr():
    # parentheses are for grouping and (as a bonus) for a pretty indentation
    s = ("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
         "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
    print s
```

To quote an [informal introduction to Python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html):

> Two string literals next to each other are automatically concatenated;
>   the first line above could also have been written word = 'Help' 'A';
>   this only works with two literals, not with arbitrary string
>   expressions.

```
>>> s = 'a' 'b'
>>> s
'ab'
>>> s = 'a''b' # space is not necessary
>>> s
'ab'
```

A side note: the concatenation is performed during the compilation to bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(pr)

 0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb')
```

Probably this concatenation tradition comes from C:

```
// prints "hello world"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("hello" " world");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest ways among the 5 :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using double or single triple quote:

```
>>> string_A = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
... this is also my content
... this is also my content
... this is also my content"""
>>>
>>> print string_A
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
this is also my content
this is also my content
this is also my content
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it boils down to how much screen real-estate you are afforded.

You could use concatenation..

```
string_a = "this is my content"
string_a += "this is also my content"
```

Comment: But this makes 2 operations instead of 1